# Which one out of the two is correct and sounds idiomatic

Tags: gerunds, possessives

Me going to a strip club can ruin my social image.

My going to a strip club can ruin my social image.

Well I guess that isn't actually the case. I think using possessive or pronoun actually depends on the sentence itself . For example I want to see you smiling ... I want to see your smiling. This doesnt make sense. However i want to see your smiling face does. Similarly I want to hear you singing (here in possessive it means I want to hear you while singing) . I want to hear your singing (here singing is a noun). So they both are right. But have different meanings

Comment: Your two "strip" examples are fine (note "strip club", not "stripping club"), the latter with "my" being a tad more formal. "Me" and "my" are both pronouns, the latter being genitive case. "I want to see you smiling" is fine, but not "your smiling" since there is no noun "smiling" in this context. "I want to hear you singing" is fine too. "I want to hear your singing" has a different meaning; "singing" is a noun, and it could mean you want to listen to the person's voice on a recording like a record or CD.

Comment: You're expected to [edit] your [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140036/which-one-outta-the-two-choices-is-correct-and-sounds-idiomatical) (not delete it) to explain why the duplicate answer was inadequate and request additional information from respondents.

Answer (score -1):

**My going to  the ...**

The subject in that sentence is the gerund “going”. It is described with the adverbial phrase “to the strip club” and by the possessive “My”.

Potentially you could use the rather formal sounding sentence “I, going to a strip club, can ruin my social image.” but in this case it is “I” rather the act of going that is doing the ruining. You can’t use the objective from “Me” as the subject.

Comment: That's what i was thinking i can't obviously use me here. Right?

Comment: @user236989 No, the subject is the clause "Me/my going to a strip club".

Comment: ???? Could you please explain

Comment: The subject of the sentence is “[Me|My] going to strip clubs”. It is the act of going that can ruin my social reputation. We use the gerund (a verb-used-as-noun) form “going” and we describe it with the possessive “my”. I you really want to use “me” as the subject, you’ll need to use the subjective pronoun “I”. @user236989, could you be more specific about what you don't understand?

Comment: What did billJ say? I couldnt understand